# Removing clipped side in vtk Surface Rendered output

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, vtk

I am doing another VTK program in MFC window by clipping planes and I am getting the output like the image shown below:

[https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vtk.org%2Fpipermail%2Fvtkusers%2Fattachments%2F20030724%2F6f1e4e82%2Fattachment.gif&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vtk.org%2Fpipermail%2Fvtkusers%2F2003-July.txt&docid=Cup_tPiymEIUrM&tbnid=01QfYF1g5tZ2gM%3A&vet=12ahUKEwiK6rCe0dHgAhWPiHAKHYcsBpM4yAEQMyhaMFp6BAgBEFs..i&w=1037&h=768&itg=1&bih=592&biw=1280&q=vtkplane%20clip%20example&ved=2ahUKEwiK6rCe0dHgAhWPiHAKHYcsBpM4yAEQMyhaMFp6BAgBEFs&iact=mrc&uact=8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4vGH.gif)

but I need to get the output like the below image
[https://vtk.org/Wiki/images/d/d1/ClipClosedSurface.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSYvi.png)

Can anybody help.I also tried using VTK mask.but I am not getting the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the result by referring and researching the below example and some other VTK sites

https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Meshes/CapClip